# How to pop the previous view controller from a navigation stack?

Tags: ios, swift, memory-leaks, uinavigationcontroller, viewcontroller

I use the navigation controller to push from view to view, but I don't pop any of the views that I push. So as I load a view I would like to pop the previous one from the stack.

Code for pushing views:

```
var identities = [String]()

identities = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"]

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let vcName = identities[indexPath.row]
    let viewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: vcName)
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController!, animated: true)

}
```

Test code for popping views (not what I want tho):

```
self.navigationController?.viewControllers.remove(at: 0)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Solved:

@DonMag helped walk me through the proper use and placement of that line of code.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uinavigationcontroller/1621886-popviewcontroller ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's really much simpler:

```
self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
```

Comment: Where were you putting your original `.remove(at: 0)` line?

Comment: The problem is that the original I put in viewdidload and when I put your code in its place, it pops me out of the view right away. I was basically covering my tracks as the next view loads.

Comment: ok - when do you want to pop back to your original view controller? on a button tap? after a time?

Comment: Yes, a button tap.

Comment: ok - then that line of code goes in your button tap code - which you probably set up as an `@IBAction`

Comment: I'm using a tableview, not sure of how I should go about putting in your code there.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142850/discussion-between-donmag-and-slavic-the-slavic).

Answer (score 1):

This is what worked for me:

```
var navigationArray = self.navigationController?.viewControllers

navigationArray.remove(at: 0)

self.navigationController?.viewControllers = navigationArray
```

Comment: I implemented this and it's real close to working. The only problem is with every time you push from the initial view controller (a small memory increase). Can't put this code there because it will just delete itself. All the other views seem to be fine. Any suggestions?